# Uncaught RangeError: `options.awareOfUnicodeTokens` must be set to `true` to use `YYYY` In date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datepicker

I am using date packer in my demo react project .
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker
Every thing is working fine, but I have one issue `whenever I remove one text from date value it gives me this error`

> Uncaught RangeError: `options.awareOfUnicodeTokens` must be set to
>   `true` to use `YYYY` token; see: https://git.io/fxCyr
>       at throwProtectedError (nk7475yjwl.codesandbox.io/node_modules/react-datepicker/lib/index.js:2211)
>       at parse (nk7475yjwl.codesandbox.io/node_modules/react-datepicker/lib/index.js:5733)
>       at parseDate (nk7475yjwl.codesandbox.io/node_modules/react-datepicker/lib/index.js:5962)
>       at DatePicker._this.handleChange (nk7475yjwl.codesandbox.io/node_modules/react-datepicker/lib/index.js:8536)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:145)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:195)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:248)
>       at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:262)
>       at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:593)
>       at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:615)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:713)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:724)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:692)
>       at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:855)
>       at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:864)
>       at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:4857)
>       at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:17498)
>       at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2189)
>       at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4936)
>       at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:17553)
>       at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2208)
>       at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4913)

Steps to produce bug

1. Run the application.It shows `09-Dec-1998`
2. Try to remove `8` from field or from `1998`. it shows above error

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/nk7475yjwl

git link
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it states [here](https://git.io/fxCyr) , YY and YYYY that represent the local week-numbering year (44, 01, 00, 17) are often confused with yy and yyyy that represent the the calendar year.

Try Replacing **dd-MMM-YYYY** with **dd-MMM-yyyy**